# Mapping association does not execute after_destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I change my model's associations through setting the collection, neither my after_destroy nor my after_remove callbacks fire.

```rb
if image_params[:tags]
    @image.tags = image_params[:tags].map { |tag|
    Tag.create(title: tag) unless Tag.where(title: tag).exists?
    Tag.find_by(title: tag)
  }
end

class TagRelation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

  # Destroy tag if no other items are related
  after_destroy do
    self.tag.check_count
  end
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tag_relations, dependent: :destroy, after_remove: :check_count
  has_many :gallery_images, through: :tag_relations, source_type: 'GalleryImage', source: :taggable
  has_many :streams, through: :tag_relations, source_type: 'Stream', source: :taggable

  validates :title, uniqueness: true

  def count
    self.tag_relations.count
  end

  def check_count
    self.destroy if self.count === 0
  end
end
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to do, what you are expecting and what you are actually getting?

Comment: I have a join table and model called TagRelation, when someone disassociates their tag from a taggable model (polymorphic), I want that destroyed TagRelation to check if the associated Tag still has another TagRelation. IF not, I want that Tag to be destroyed.

Comment: How do you "disassociate" a Tag from a taggable model?

Comment: It's all in my code sample: I map the "tags" param (an array) to the image.tags association. If the tag is not in that array anymore, it automatically gets disassociated and the TagRelation is properly destroyed. Just not the Tag if tag.count === 0.

Comment: Have you looked at the [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) method? If you use it with the `:allow_destroy` option, objects will be destroyed thus your `after_destroy` callbacks will be executed.